# Synchronize current folder in multiple terminals

Tags: bash, terminal, process-management

Today I came across an interesting idea - is it possible to synchronize multiple terminals somehow, so when I change directory in one of them, it gets changed automatically in the others?

I think it could be possible by forking them from one common parent process, but I have no idea if there is some way to make them communicate like this.

I'm using Lubuntu 17.10, so I'd prefer some solution using Bash, if possible.

Comment: Would screen be no good for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adapting [ClusterSSH](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh/wiki) to this, but there's no way within bash itself.